# why does `git init` break an elastic beanstalk deployment? how can i recover?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a node app on Elastic Beanstalk that worked perfectly. Then I figured I should get it under version control. After doing that, the deployment broke and instead of serving the react UI from the static server, it just served an empty json object with a 500 status code.

Running the project locally, the app still worked perfectly, so it seemed like some sort of environmental change?

The way I figured out what had even happened was that I placed the `.git` folder inside a `temp` folder above my project folder, completely out of the way of my project folder, redeployed, and everything worked smoothly again.

Why did this happen?

Also, how can I safely replace my `.git` folder in the project folder without breaking deployment?

Comment: How did it fail? What sort of errors did you see?

Comment: The express app was serving 500’s for all the requests, index.html, favicon.ico, etc. I tried to log something with middleware at the top of the app, but it seemed to be breaking before it even hit that.

Comment: Does anything in your app search the entire project tree? It might be reading the `.git` directory.

Comment: That's a good thought, @Schwern, but the app continued to work fine locally, it was just broken in production. I updated my answer with that crucial detail.

Comment: Creating a repository should not have changed the deployment at all. The repository should not be on the production server. You deploy *from* the repository.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. It turns out that eb uses git to create the app if it is being used for version control. I thought git should be unrelated to how eb works, but I think it probably makes sense WRT CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some well placed console.logs I figured out why this was breaking.

I thought `eb deploy` was copying the contents of my local directory to use for the deployment, but it appears to try to use the git repo first, if there is one, and fall back to using the local files if not.

The app I was trying to deploy has a build folder for the front end that I keep out of the repo with a .gitignore file. So Elastic Beanstalk was not supplying those files (which were present in my local folder) for the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

> Why did this happen?

A [500 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Server_error_responses) (internal server) means you need to access the Elastic Beanstalk logs in order to understand what is going on.

Use [`eb logs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html) or [access those logs through the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html):

[image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/images/environment-management-logs.png]

Comment: I had been looking at those, but couldn't find much beyond the 500's I already knew I was getting. The app was showing as healthy otherwise. I'll attempt to reproduce the issue on a non-production env and post the logs, though. I'm sure I'm missing something.